# How to select if a given data exists in multiple tables and then update to table with result (only one table brings result)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update, union-all

Somethings like:

```
UPDATE Table(Customers or Customers2) SET City ="A"
FROM (
SELECT City FROM Customers where id=1
UNION
SELECT City FROM Customers2 where id=1)
```

Comment: Somethings like:

UPDATE Table(Customers or Customers2) SET City ="A" FROM ( SELECT City FROM Customers where id=1 UNION SELECT City FROM Customers2 where id=1)

Comment: I recommend that you read this article and try posting your question again.  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: you can't update a table or anothers  table  ..

Comment: You need to run this with 2 different update statements. `UPDATE t SET City = 'A' FROM table1 AS t WHERE id = 1` and then `UPDATE t SET City = 'A' FROM table2 AS t WHERE id = 1`

Comment: Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can only update one table at a time in a given `UPDATE` statement.  You need to use two updates:

```
UPDATE Customers 
    SET City = 'A'
    WHERE id = 1;

UPDATE Customers2 
    SET City = 'A'
    WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much.